# What is the safe way to allow Java 7 to run on SELinux

Tags: linux, java, selinux

**Short version:**  What is the most secure way to allow Java 7 to run on (with?) SELinux?

**Long version:**

Sorry in advance if I use incorrect terminology.  I'm really just a Java developer with a meager smattering of Linux skills.

I just installed Java 7 on CentOS release 5.3 (Final) that is apparently has Security Enhanced Linux.  After the install was complete (which I "installed" by unzipping the tar.gz file from Oracle in `/usr/java/jdk/jdk1.7.0_25`), I ran `java -version` and got this error:

```
Error: dl failure on line 864
Error: failed /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so,
      because /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so:
      cannot restore segment prot after reloc: Permission denied`
```

I found a few articles stating this can be due to SELinux and to try `setenforce 0` and see if the problem goes away.  I ran that command and Java worked.  But these same articles say that leaving `setenforce 0` on an Internet connected host is dangerous, and my host is connected to the Internet.

There are other articles that suggest this next approach, but also say it can be dangerous, so I haven't tried it yet.

```
chcon -t textrel_shlib_t /usr/jre1.7.0_10/lib/i386/client/libjvm.so
```

...in the above command the path at the end of the command is replaced with the path of my JDK.

What I can't find is something "official" (which can mean many things) on how to run Java 7 on (with?) SELinux safely.  Does anyone have any information for me?

**Edit:**  I discovered an article that referred to editing `/etc/selinux/config`.  I have set as shown in the sample below.  This allows Java to run but I assume I now have some security holes.

```
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#       enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#       permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#       disabled - SELinux is fully disabled.
SELINUX=permissive
# SELINUXTYPE= type of policy in use. Possible values are:
#       targeted - Only targeted network daemons are protected.
#       strict - Full SELinux protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

Comment: The `chcon` solution looks reasonable. The last solution isn't much different than `setenforce 0`.

Comment: Can you just install it in your home directory instead?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen:  Well, I suppose I could, but it runs as a daemon, a Tomcat server to be more specific, and somehow it feels a little sloppy to have a Tomcat server running from my home directory.

Comment: Basically a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/14723474/560648.

Answer (score 2):

1. Clean up the current installation
2. Download the RPM file (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html)

   ```
   yum -y localinstall /path/to/downloaded-java.rpm
   ```

rest will be taken care.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you elaborate on "Clean up the current installation"?  Do you mean remove what I installed?

Comment: Yes, that's right! Remove your current Oracle Java installation. 
Please follow "Self-extracting file uninstall" http://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_uninstall.xml#self

Comment: Why is this the solution?

Comment: If @LightnessRacesinOrbit doesn't know why this is the proper solution, please read up on [What SELinux is](http://selinuxproject.org/page/Main_Page).  Basically the RPM script sets the proper permissions ACL's etc

Comment: @eyoung100: No, my point is that this answer does not explain anything. It should explain _why_ removing and replacing the installation should resolve the problem, as well as giving the steps to do so. Also I ask because I installed from RPM but still got the problem.