# Can't start tomcat in digital ocean's CentOS server?

Tags: centos, tomcat

I am trying to configure a CentOs server in DigitalOcean. I have followed all those steps mentioned in their website.This is the link of various steps to configure server. [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-centos-7). I followed all but unfortunately no getting expected result. I have followed till end of step `Install Systemd Unit File` in this link. Is there any problem in setting `JAVA_HOME`? I followed answer in this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/235891/tomcat-8-will-not-start-after-initial-install). But not getting expected result. Every time I check tomcat status , I get this

```
tomcat.service - Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since রবি 2019-01-20 07:30:17 UTC; 7s ago
  Process: 21958 ExecStop=/bin/kill -15 $MAINPID (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 21945 ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 21956 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

জানু 20 07:30:17 IRDCentOS systemd[1]: Unit tomcat.service entered f....
জানু 20 07:30:17 IRDCentOS systemd[1]: tomcat.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

trace of `journalctl -u tomcat.service`

```
-- Logs begin at রবি 2019-01-20 08:02:54 UTC, end at রবি 2019-01-20 08:22:42 UTC
জানু 20 08:22:16 IRDCentOS systemd[1]: Starting Apache Tomcat Web Application Con
জানু 20 08:22:16 IRDCentOS systemd[1]: Started Apache Tomcat Web Application Cont
জানু 20 08:22:16 IRDCentOS systemd[1]: tomcat.service: control process exited, co
জানু 20 08:22:16 IRDCentOS systemd[1]: Unit tomcat.service entered failed state.
জানু 20 08:22:16 IRDCentOS systemd[1]: tomcat.service failed.
জানু 20 08:22:26 IRDCentOS systemd[1]: tomcat.service holdoff time over, scheduli
জানু 20 08:22:26 IRDCentOS systemd[1]: Starting Apache Tomcat Web Application Con
জানু 20 08:22:26 IRDCentOS startup.sh[9783]: Existing PID file found during start
জানু 20 08:22:26 IRDCentOS startup.sh[9783]: Removing/clearing stale PID file.
জানু 20 08:22:26 IRDCentOS systemd[1]: Started Apache Tomcat Web Application Cont
জানু 20 08:22:26 IRDCentOS systemd[1]: tomcat.service: control process exited, co
জানু 20 08:22:26 IRDCentOS systemd[1]: Unit tomcat.service entered failed state.
জানু 20 08:22:26 IRDCentOS systemd[1]: tomcat.service failed.
জানু 20 08:22:42 IRDCentOS systemd[1]: tomcat.service holdoff time over, scheduli
জানু 20 08:22:42 IRDCentOS systemd[1]: Starting Apache Tomcat Web Application Con
জানু 20 08:22:42 IRDCentOS startup.sh[9819]: Existing PID file found during start
জানু 20 08:22:42 IRDCentOS startup.sh[9819]: Removing/clearing stale PID file.
জানু 20 08:22:42 IRDCentOS systemd[1]: Started Apache Tomcat Web Application Cont
জানু 20 08:22:42 IRDCentOS systemd[1]: tomcat.service: control process exited, co
জানু 20 08:22:42 IRDCentOS systemd[1]: Unit tomcat.service entered failed state.
জানু 20 08:22:42 IRDCentOS systemd[1]: tomcat.service failed.
```

And in `cataliina.out` trace is

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: If the number of processors is expected to increase from one, then you should configure the number of parallel GC threads appropriately using -XX:ParallelGCThreads=N
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `journalctl -u tomcat.service` to the question?

Comment: @Haxiel I updated my question. Can you please check?

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like the logs are being written elsewhere, and not to the systemd journal. Can you look for the directory `/opt/tomcat/logs` in your system and see if you can find any information there? There should be a log file with the name `catalina`, which is Tomcat's standard log.

Comment: @Haxiel, Yes , there it is !

Comment: Since the server is failing to start, that log should contain some error messages for you to check further. You can also post the logs from the last startup here, so that we can check.

Comment: @Haxiel I added log file of `catalina.out`. Please check !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88531/discussion-between-haxiel-and-avijit-barua).

Comment: I would advise detailing you your words the problem and what you have done. The answer you are linking to does not seem particular good advice, but I might not looked at it well. Please tell us what is your java home and if you installed java.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, I am following the link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-centos-7 to configure server. But Tomcat is not starting. And using command `ls - l /etc/alternatives/java` I am getting java home and setting at `JAVA_HOME`. But tomcat is not starting

Comment: @Haxiel have you found any solution ?